# How to prove a linear space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I would like to prove the following:

Is the set $V=R^2$ with:

$ +: V \times V \to V$: $((x,y),(x',y')$ $\to(x \cdot x' -y \cdot y', x \cdot y'+y \cdot x')$

$ \cdot:\mathbb{R}  \times V \to V$: $(a,(x,y)) \to (a \cdot x, a \cdot y)$

a linear space?

- property: I would start with $x,y,z$ with $x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2),z=(z_1,z_2)$
  in order to show that $(x+y)+z$ or  $(z+y)+x$

Here I just dont know how to proceed...

Comment: Hint: compare $(1,1) + (1,1)$ to $2\cdot (1,1)$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @HiThere: You have to run through axioms of vectorspace
and to proof of all rules are satisfied with the given addition
and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Yes thank you. I know, I just confused with the mapping...do I have to prove the addition and multiplication seperately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the answer by David Wheeler, here is a way to see it that just requires you to do a simple computation.

If this was a vector space, then we would have $v + v = 1\cdot v + 1\cdot v = (1+1)\cdot v = 2\cdot v$ for all $v\in V$ by the distributive rule.

But if $v = (1,1)$ then $2\cdot v = (2,2)$ while $v + v = (1\cdot 1 - 1\cdot 1, 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1) = (0,2)$, so the distributive rule fails to hold.

Answer (score 3):

A hint: Show that $(0,0)$ has no additive inverse. This is tricky: the additive identity is $(1,0)$, since:

$(x,y) + (1,0) = (x\cdot 1 - y\cdot 0, x\cdot 0 + y \cdot 1) = (x,y)$ and

$(1,0) + (x,y) = (1\cdot x - 0 \cdot y, 1 \cdot y + 0\cdot x) = (x,y)$

So you need to show there is NO $(x,y)$ with:

$(0,0) + (x,y) = (1,0)$.